# WCF Versioning restful way problem

Tags: wcf, versioning, backwards-compatibility

i have two methods in  Icontact and wcf service, i want to version one method for new requirement.
and want existing clients to call old code. and new client to call the new changed method and existing method for backward compatibility.

code:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.testk.com/1/11", Name = "cService")]
public interface ICService
{
   [OperationContract(Name="GetWorkingDetails")]
   void GetWorkingDetails(int a);

   void GetList(int a);
}

//service Implementation
public class MyService : ICService
{
   [WebGet]
   void GetWorkingDetails(int a)
   {
     ////
   }

   [WebGet]
   void GetList(int a)
   {
      ////
   }
}
```

**here i am versioning.....**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.testk.com/2/11", Name = "cService")]
  public interface ICServicev1
{
    [OperationContract(Name="GetWorkingDetails")]
    void GetWorkingDetailsV2(int a);
}

<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="v0"
          contract="ICService" />
<endpoint address="r1" behaviorConfiguration="AjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="v1"
          contract="ICServicev1" />
```

When I call the existing method it works great, also when I call `service.svc/r1/GetWorkingDetails` it works great. But I want to also call `service.svc/r1/GetList` which is in previous contract. How can I call this for backward compatibility.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I guess `service.svc/r1/GetList` is not possible. Because your not inheriting `ICService` to `ICServicev1` (i.e `public interface ICServicev1 : ICService`). Infact you can achieve this with the following way.

1) Create `ICServiceCommon` interface with the `void GetList(int a);` method.

2) Inherit `ICServiceCommon` interface to `ICService` and `ICServicev1`[`public interface ICService : ICServiceCommon` and  `public interface ICServicev1 : ICServiceCommon`]

3) Implement `ICService` and `ICServicev1` interfaces to `MyService` class [`public class MyService : ICService, ICServicev1`].

The old version client call the the same methods. [backward compatibility]

```
service.svc/GetWorkingDetails
service.svc/GetList
```

and new client can call

```
service.svc/r1/GetWorkingDetailsV2
service.svc/r1/GetList
```

Hope this approach is useful.